# NestJS-CRUD: How to set an alias for column name?

Tags: crud, nestjs, typeorm, react-admin

I am using `@nestjsx/crud-typeorm` to create a CRUD REST API for `react-admin`. One of the requirements of `react-admin` is that every item in the response needs to have an `id` field. The database that I am working with uses `item_id` as the ID field instead.

How do I create an alias in my CRUD responses such as the `item_id` field is returned as `id`.

The SQL equivalent would be:
`SELECT item_id as id from TableName`

Comment: Probably you can duplicate the field in the API response itself? What is your backend working with?